# VBA_using 'Line Input' but failed (Error 62: Input past end of file)

Tags: excel, input, eof, vba

Good morning,

I've tried to write a code in order to:
1. Open a txt. file, which contains a list of files
2. Open the files in the list one by one
3.read the contents in each file and put it in the sheet

And my code is here:

```
Private Sub Boutton_Importer_Click()

list_de_controle = "TEXT;" & listPath
Open listPath For Input As #1 'open the list

Do While Not EOF(1)  'read the list
    Line Input #1, nom_de_Fich
    ActiveCell = nom_de_Fich
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    Open nom_de_Fich For Input As #2  'open a file in the list

    Do While Not EOF(1)  'read the contents in the list
        Line Input #2, contenu
        ActiveCell = contenu
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
    Close #2

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select  'go to the line below
    ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Select
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

You may find that the two part of Do While is exactly the same but the first one, for the list, runs well.
And the second one, for the contents in the file, always failed.
Could you please help me to check this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've forgotten some thing, that the first file in the list can be opened, and all the contents can be read in to sheet, but the next file can't be opened. So I think the problem is that EOF can not figure if it's already reached the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Do While Not EOF(1)  'read the contents in the list
    Line Input #2, contenu
    ActiveCell = contenu
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop
Close #2
```

You're telling the code to loop through and `Line Input` from file `#2` but the condition is based on reaching the end of the file in file `#1`.

As you're not actually moving through file `#1` the statement `EOF(1)` will **never** be true - this loop will run and inevitably hit the end of file `#2` at which point you will get the error

> Input past end of file

---

**To fix your problem:**

try something like this instead:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim textFile1 As Byte
Dim textFile2 As Byte
Dim tfArray1 As Variant
Dim tfArray2 As Variant

textFile1 = FreeFile

Open listPath For Input As #textFile1
    tfArray1 = Split(Input(LOF(textFile1), textFile1), vbCrLf)
Close #textFile1

For Each tfile In tfArray1

    textFile2 = FreeFile

    Open tfile For Input As #textFile2
        tfArray2 = Split(Input(LOF(textFile2), textFile2), vbCrLf)
    Close #textFile2

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(tfArray2) + 1, 1).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tfArray2)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And I've tried to change just the EOF(1) to EOF(2), and it works. But I don't know if that will cause some problems or not?

Comment: Shouldn't do - but I updated my answer to include a better way of doing what you're trying to achieve anyway so give that a try if you want. Don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped

Comment: I see! I'll have a try. And of course I'll give a mark! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good afternoon, sorry for such a delay, I've almost finished my project and I've tried your code but it shows me a error message : Subscript out of range. I've tried to change LOF to EOF but still failed. So could you take a look of that please?

Comment: It's tfarray1 = Split(Input(LOF(textfile1), textfile1), vbCrLf)

Comment: make sure `listPath` has been declared properly with the full file path. That error is because there's nothing in the file that it's trying to read.

Comment: Ah really? I think listPath has had something inside cause I've replaced tfarray1 = Split(Input(LOF(textfile1), textfile1), vbCrLf) by some lines else and it works. I'll check it again otherwise and give you more details. Thanks!

Comment: Can you jump in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge)?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment, I've reveived a couple of comments recently. I'll see the chat room laterly. Thank you.